# "Why do you think you are suitable for this position" interview question

Tags: interviewing

I always get stumped on questions at the end of an interview like: Why do you think you are suitable for this position of senior test analyst which you applied for?

I'm a senior QA looking for change. I explain my roles and responsibilities like how I handled the team of junior testers, how I handled any issues in the team, explaining my skills, but I feel the interviewers are not satisfied with the answer I provide.

Can someone please explain how I should answer and what to highlight?

Comment: it's totally dependant of what is the new job you want for a change.

Comment: I always say "I'll make you look good"

Answer (score 1):

Focus on two things.
1- Skill set 
2- Core values

convince them that you are having all the required skills for this job.
and you strongly believe on core values of this organization, if possible give some examples where you have lived these core values in real life.

This might be a trick question as well, to see how confident you are and how you rate yourself. Because at the end of day it does not matter what other think about you what matters most is do you believe in youself or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the Job Spec they provided, and show you have the related experience on your profile point by point. It's a simple but a core question to know you better.

Don't feel offended with that question, because they are dealing with such candidates that they don't know what kind of role they applied to, even after they show up to interview. (I am being one of them sometimes.)